# Merge values for same key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Is that possible to use `awk` to values of same key into one row?
For instance

```
a,100
b,200
a,131
a,102
b,203
b,301
```

Can I convert them to a file like this:

```
a,100,131,102
b,200,203,301
```

Comment: Use associative array, tons of examples on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1] FS $2} END{for (i in a) print i a[i]}' file

a,100,131,102
b,200,203,301
```

We use `-F,` to use comma as delimiter and use array `a` to keep aggregated value.

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option,

```
perl -F, -lane '$a{$F[0]} = "$a{$F[0]},$F[1]"; END{for $k (sort keys %a){print "$k$a{$k}"}}' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the `@F` array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace.
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `-F` autosplit modifier, in this case splits on `,`

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with `$F[0]`
`$F[0]` is the first element in `@F` (the key)
`$F[1]` is the second element in `@F` (the value)
`%a` is a hash which stores a string containing all matches of each key

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

If you presort the input, it is possible to use `sed` to join the lines, e.g.:

```
sort foo | sed -nE ':a; $p; N; s/^([^,]+)([^\n]+)\n\1/\1\2/; ta; P; s/.+\n//; ba'
```

### A bit more explanation

The above one-liner can be saved into a script file. See below for a commented version.

*parse.sed*

```
# A goto label
:a

# Always print when on the last line
$p

# Read one more line into pattern space and join the
# two lines if the key fields are identical
N
s/^([^,]+)([^\n]+)\n\1/\1\2/

# Jump to label 'a' and redo the above commands if the
# substitution command was successful
ta

# Assuming sorted input, we have now collected all the
# fields for this key, print it and move on to the next
# key
P
s/.+\n//
ba
```

The logic here is as follows:

1. Assume sorted input.
2. Look at two consecutive lines. If their key fields match, remove the key from the second line and append the value to the first line.
3. Repeat 2. until key matching fails.
4. Print the collected values and reset to collect values for the next key.

Run it like this:

```
sort foo | sed -nEf parse.sed
```

Output:

```
a,100,102,131
b,200,203,301
```

Answer (score 0):

With [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash -st, -g1 collapse 2 <ip.txt
a,100,131,102
b,200,203,301
```

From manual:

> **-s, --sort**
>
> sort the input before grouping; this removes the need to manually pipe the input through 'sort'
>
> **-t, --field-separator=X**
>
> use X instead of TAB as field delimiter
>
> **-g, --group=X[,Y,Z]**
>
> group via fields X,[Y,Z]
>
> **collapse**
>
> comma-separated list of all input values